# Сохранение переноса строк в textarea в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea

Есть `textarea` с классом `modal-description`, я получаю её значение с помощью *jquery* `let description =  $('.modal-description').val()` Но при получении значения у меня не сохраняются переносы строки. Как я могу решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> при получении значения у меня не сохраняются переносы строки

Как Вы это определили?

```js
var text = $("#source").val();
var lines = text.split("\n");
console.log(lines.length);
$("#destination").html(lines.join("<br/>"));
```

```css
#destination {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="source">The walrus
and the carpenter
Walked for a mile
or so</textarea>
<div id="destination"></div>
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Не `.val()` а `.text()`

```js
console.log($('.modal-description').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="modal-description">
ssssssssss
ddddddddd
</textarea>
```